# Going the distance in Braid

Tags: braid

Is there a significant benefit to running through the entirety of Braid to find the stars?
I have done a little FAQ reading and determined that I have screwed up my chances of using my existing save game, and would need to restart.

Is the "second" ending worth it though?  I found Braid to be an amazing game, but a lot of drudgery would need to be overcome to get all those puzzle pieces again....if they payoff isn't that great I don't know if I'd do it.

---

Edit:

I am not a completionist by any sense of the word...basically the general concept was that I was wondering if the payoff vs the amount of work going into getting the stars would be worth it.

Comment: This might be too subjective to be answerable. Can you give an example of what would be worth it vs not worth it for you?

Comment: @AnnaLear I'm forced to agree. Collecting all the stars is itself the reward for collecting all the stars, and if you even have to ask this question I wouldn't say it is worth it for you to collect them.

Comment: Might want to rephrase this question to ask objectively what you're getting.

Comment: Why not cut out the middle man and just find the ending on youtube?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An extremely hardcore player of Braid here.

Braid is a very deep game and there are many aspects about the story/gameplay/puzzles/etc that can be either understood, or completely missed.

Getting all the stars reveals a different ending, but this ending is not straightforward at all. It's difficult to tell whether you'd understand what happens after you get the stars **and** beat the final level as you have to (I won't go into further details to avoid spoilers).

If you follow the story of Braid and are interested in every little detail, I'd say get the stars. In my opinion, it's not that difficult. It can be done on one sitting. But remember: after you get the stars, there won't be a crystal clear message explaining anything about the story. You will only open an opportunity to a different ending, which ultimately also needs a further understanding by the player.

Long story short: Get the stars, it's worth it!

Comment: One sitting, even the one that requires you to stand still for like two hours? ;3

Comment: I didn't actually sit there and watch it happen, that's true. I jumped up on the cloud and then left the room for a few hours to do some work, then got back and just took the star :)

Comment: Ditto, haha!  One time I waited too long though and I'd fallen off the cloud.

Answer (score 2):

The second ending just reveals/confirms what you might have thought the story was about if you paid attention (the story that's underneath the whole "Tim is a stalker" story).

If that's worth it to you, then it's worth it, if it's not then it's not. I found that it was worth my time because I also had fun getting the stars.